# I can't add Date layer when use ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(date, unemploy, data = economics, geom = "line", xlab = "",
           ylab = "No. of unemployed(1000s)")
presidential <- presidential[-(1 : 3), ]
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = start) , data = presidential)
```

I want to do the plot like above. But I got an error,

```
Error in Ops.Date((x - from[1]), diff(from))
```

In Hadley Wickham's book ggplot2, the above code is ok. I have also viewed questions like mine. One solution is to use numeric form of date, but if I use numeric form, the x-axis would be numeric number not date. Could anyone help me figure out how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: where are you getting ``a`` from? Also, to be clear, the error is only produced after ``+ geom_vline(xintercept = a, data = presidential)`` and not after define ``p`` on your second line?

Comment: Code works for me (except that `a` is not found). Are you using the current version of R? Maybe restart.

Comment: I am sorry I have re-edited the code.

Comment: I could plot a vertical line when I just use `intercept = as.numeric(as.Date(1970-02-03))`, but it does not work when `aes(intercept = as.numeric(start))`

Comment: `aes(xintercept = as.numeric(start))` works on my end..

Comment: @Axeman Yeah it worked on my end as well after I restart R.

Comment: Thank very much all of you!